# ERROR : Using EXEC and Select in Same Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have the following statements for my procedure

```
    DECLARE @StockA table (GoodID int,NominalQty decimal(16,2),ActualQty decimal(16,2))

    INSERT INTO @StockA(GoodID,NominalQty,ActualQty)
    EXEC ('INV.[usp_GetStorageAvailability] ' + @SysYear +',"2015-01-01",1')

    UPDATE @ReqItems 
    SET Stock = S.ActualQty , Rem = (S.ActualQty - R.Qty) FROM @ReqItems R JOIN @StockA S on R.GoodID = S.GoodID

    DECLARE @HasMinus tinyint
    SET @HasMinus = (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @ReqItems WHERE Rem < 0)

    IF @HasMinus > 0 begin
    DECLARE @GC nvarchar(10)
    SET @GC = (SELECT TOP 1 GoodCode FROM @ReqItems WHERE Rem < 0)
     SET @Outcome = 0
     SET @Descr = 'XZY'
    end


    SELECT @Outcome,@Descr
```

and i get the following error :

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

what should i do ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
SET @HasMinus = (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @ReqItems WHERE Rem < 0)
```

I think the error is pretty clear.  The `*` refers to multiple columns.  You need to choose one:

```
SET @HasMinus = (SELECT TOP 1 ?? FROM @ReqItems WHERE Rem < 0);
```

I'm not sure which column you want to select, however.

If you just want a count, you can do:

```
SELECT @HasMinus = COUNT(*) FROM @ReqItems WHERE Rem < 0;
```

This might be the intention of your code.  (Note that the `SET` isn't necessary.)